# Grabbing rows and columns from a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm buidling a landing page in SPX. Right now it is pulling in the book from the Excel file as the section header, but I want to use Column B as the section header. Then use columns C, D, E, F, and G as different lines in the landing page.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
   function populateDom(TickerData,SectionSelector){
        let spxTicker = document.getElementById('spxTicker');
        document.getElementById('spxTicker').innerHTML="";
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            console.log('TickerData[' + SectionSelector + ']:', TickerData[SectionSelector]);
            SectionName = TickerData[SectionSelector].name;
            console.log('Section [' + SectionSelector + ']: ' + SectionName);
            // document.getElementById('SectionHeader').innerText = SectionName;
            spxTicker.innerHTML="";
            TickerData[SectionSelector].data.forEach((item,index) => {
                if (index==0) {
                    spxTicker.innerHTML=item;
                } else {
                    spxTicker.innerHTML+='&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="sheetTickerDelim" style="margin-left:0.5em;"></span>&nbsp;' + item;
                }
            });
            spxTicker.innerHTML+='<span class="LastItem" id="LastItem">LAST</span>'
            console.log('spxTicker position: ' + document.getElementById('spxTicker').offsetLeft);
            resolve();
          }
        )
      }
```

Right now it is pulling in the book rather than the columns and rows